# XML tag value replace using python

Tags: python

I have an XML file where I need to replace the value inside filter tag. I have tried to parse this XML but looks like some error in this which I am unable to resolve. Can anybody please help me in replacing the value.

```
path = """
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Header>
    <header xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
      <security>
        <user>testuser</user>
        <password hashed="false">testpassword</password>
      </security>
      <requestID>XML_API_client@n</requestID>
    </header>
  </SOAP:Header>
  <SOAP:Body>
    <find>
      <fullClassName>equipment.PhysicalPort</fullClassName>
      <filter>
        <equal name="siteId" value="x.x.x.x." />
      </filter>
      <resultFilter>
        <attribute>objectFullName</attribute>
        <attribute>displayedName</attribute>
        <attribute>portName</attribute>
        <attribute>description</attribute>
        <attribute>lagMembershipId</attribute>
        <attribute>encapType</attribute>
        <attribute>mode</attribute>
        <attribute>speed</attribute>
        <attribute>mtuValue</attribute>
      </resultFilter>
    </find>
    <find xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
      <fullClassName>ethernetequipment.EthernetPortSpecifics</fullClassName>
    <filter>
      <equal name="siteId" value="x.x.x.x." />
    </filter>
    <resultFilter>
      <attribute>autoNegotiate</attribute>
      <attribute>downWhenLooped</attribute>
    </resultFilter>
  </find>
"""
```

The other way I tried:

```
path = '../request.xml'
IP = '"' + '63.130.111.89' + '"' + '/>'
f = open('test.xml', 'w+')
for line in open(path, 'r'):
    output_line = line
    string1, string2 = "siteId", "value"
    if string1 in output_line:
        value = output_line.split("value"'=', 1)[1]
        output_line = str.replace(output_line, value, IP)
f.write(output_line)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. The easier you make it for us to understand your question, the more likely you'll get a helpful response. Non-code text should _not_ be indented by four spaces (that makes it a code block). Code blocks should be indented _or_ fenced with `\`\`\``. And giant blocks of XML should be formatted for easy reading, not crammed onto one single line.

Comment: The correct thing would indeed be to parse the XML and then patch the representation you get.
Since you say you cannot parse the XML due to errors in the XML the first option would be to fix the XML.
If that cannot be done then you could use regular expressions (`import re`) to replace the content: `output_line = re.sub(r'value="[^"]+"', 'value="63.130.111.89"', output_line)`